# Sum column in array if is exactly equal to a existing in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Well guys, I stay mounting one cart of products and I save this items selected on sessionStorage, my JSON saved is this:

```
[
  {
    "product": {
      "ref": "42101",
      "price": 390,
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"
    },
    "combinations": [
      {
        "type": "REVAS",
        "option": "REVVNL"
      },
      {
        "type": "CORAS",
        "option": "VNL132"
      },
      {
        "type": "APCAB",
        "option": "VNL132"
      }
    ],
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "product": {
      "ref": "42101",
      "price": 390,
      "image": "https://via.placeholder.com/200x200"
    },
    "combinations": [
      {
        "type": "REVAS",
        "option": "REVVNL"
      },
      {
        "type": "CORAS",
        "option": "VNL132"
      },
      {
        "type": "APCAB",
        "option": "VNL132"
      }
    ],
    "amount": 5
  }
]
```

All, parameters and order is equal, only the amount is variable, is possible verify if the object is equal and sum the key amount?

Comment: do you have always two object inside of the array? what do you like to get back from the function? an object?

Comment: NinaScholz, no is a a dynamic array of objects, but, the keys is equal for all objects, only the value of key is different

Comment: @TiagoPaza, please add your try.

Comment: @NinaScholz I have an idea but I don't know how to execute it ... I thought of going through the array with forEach, and I would separate it first by the keys: "product.ref" if there is more than one, I create an array with the same ones, starting from new array i would go through the for the combinations and use the find function to see if the "type" and "option" is the same but I don't know how to use find without a static string.

In your opinion is possible?

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?, do you want to sum all the same products into one product object? or what?

Comment: @TiagoPaza, what ever you try, it's fine. don't forget to add this to the question.

Comment: Yes, is reduce to a one product but with a sum of amount

Comment: @NinaScholz I managed to solve a part, how could I do to iterate the combinations?

Answer (score -1):

I solved it in parts, I'm already grouping and making the sum. But I need to check and iterate the `combinations` and if the combinations are different, I create a new object, is it possible?

```
let budgetMap = [{
    product: '',
    combinations: '',
    amount: 0,
}];

let reserseMap = [];

for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(budget)) {
    if (typeof reserseMap[value.product.ref] !== 'undefined') {
        key = reserseMap[value.product.ref];
    } else {
        reserseMap[value.product.ref] = key;
    }

    budgetMap[key].product = value.product;
    budgetMap[key].combinations = value.combinations;
    budgetMap[key].amount += value.amount;
}
```